# Search function from JSON structure

Tags: arrays, json, function, search, svelte

I am looking for a solution to search JSON values based on the user input in the search field.

For example: if the user keys in ASD, any data that contain ASD in the Json values should display.

I found an example which works like how i wanted it to be. However, they are not using JSON structure.

Here's the code that I have followed:
App.svelte:

```
<script>
    import Search from "./Search.svelte";
    
      const data = [
    "Metrics Server",
    "Node.js",
    "Virtual Machine",
    "Virtual Private Server",
  ];
</script>

<Search autofocus {data} let:filtered>
  <ul>
    {#each filtered as item}
    <li>{item}</li>
    {/each}
  </ul>
</Search>
```

Search.svelte

```
<script>
import {onMount} from "svelte";
export let autofocus = false;
export let data = [];

let input = undefined;
let value ="";

onMount(() =>{
    if(autofocus) {
        input.focus();
    }
});

$: filtered = data.filter((item) => 
    item.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
 </script>
<style>
ul{
    list-style:none;
}
</style>
<input bind:this="{input}" type="search" bind:value />


<ul>
{#each filtered as item}
<li>{item}</li>
{/each}
</ul>
```

This code does not work for JSON structure such as:
{"name": "tommy, "class":"a"},
{"name": "dummy, "class":"b"} ...

It will return an error like:

```
item.toLowerCase is not a function
```

How do I implement a search function that will return me the name if the user search for "tommy"

This is how i am retrieving the Json data:

```
let info ="";
onMount(async () =>{
     const resp = await fetch('https:xx.xxx.xxx')
        info = await resp.json();      
    });
```

And the data I am getting back is in this format: [editted]

```
[    {
    "table_schema": "x",
    "table_name": "a",
    "column_name": "typname",
    "data_type": "name",
    "character_maximum_length": null
},
{
    "table_schema": "b",
    "table_name": "x",
    "column_name": "typnamespace",
    "data_type": "oid",
    "character_maximum_length": null
}]
```

I have edited my real JSON file. The code does works for my dummy JSON but not the real one. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have an array of objects, e.g. `data = [{ name: 'tommy', class: 'a' }, { name: 'eric', class: 'b' }]`?

Comment: Yes. I am actually fetching data from database using the fetch function. i will edit my post with my code for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to loop through each of the properties on your items and compare each of them:

- first loop over the items with `data.filter`
- get all the props of each item `Object.keys(item)`
- check if at least one matches a condition `.some`
- compare the key in the item to the value `item[key].toLower....`

```js
$: filtered = data.filter(item => 
   Object.keys(item).some(key => 
     item[key].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
   )
);
```

Note that this code assumes **all** items in your array are objects, it will fail if you have a mix between objects and strings:

`[ "Tommy", { name: "Sammy" }]`

Here the first element doesn't really have 'keys'. You would have to add an additional check for that first.

Comment: Hi Stephane! Appreciate your help. I have yet to try out this. I will let you if i face any difficulties and will vote your answer if its working. I have edited my code. Does that array worked for this code?

Comment: The code will work with the array you pasted, but beware that it will check **all** properties for a match and not just the name

Comment: Hi Stephane, the code works! However, The code works if the JSON values are in the string format. But if I have null as the values then it does not work. Do u know how can I solve this issue and how can I search using different keys? Much appreciated

Comment: To cover null values you will have to expand the part that does the actual comparison to handle those cases, a simple `if` should be able to do so.  If you want to search on specific keys only, you can skip the entire `Object.keys` part and just check the key directly no ?

Comment: Right now i am getting error such as: "Search.svelte:23 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null
    at Search.svelte:23
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at Search.svelte:22
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at Object.$$self.$$.update (Search.svelte:21)
    at update (index.mjs:726)
    at flush (index.mjs:699)"

Comment: Hi Denise, in the function after `key =>` you have to check if `item[key]` is not null before doing the comparison, probably something like `item[key] !== null ? item[key].toLowerCase.... : false`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223738/discussion-between-denise-and-stephane-vanraes).